# Rails cancan authorization based on association being denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have the snippet below in my `ability.rb` file:

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.group === 1
    can :manage, Task do |task|
      task.user.id === user.id
    end
  end 
end
```

The user `has_many` tasks and each task `belongs_to` a user.  The task record being requested (7) has a `user_id` of 4.  The user sending the request has a `user_id` of 4.

In the tasks show method, I have this snippet to authorize and return the data:

```
def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    authorize! :read, @current_user

    render json: @task, root: "task"
end
```

Why would it be denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the task, not the current_user.  The current_user is assumed:

```
def show
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])

  authorize! :read, @task

  render json: @task, root: "task"
end
```

In your abilities file you could write it like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :manage, Task do |task|
    task.user.id == user.id && user.group == 1
  end
end
```